# iPad orientation change - How to animate load of new nib/xib

Tags: ipad, animation, ios4, xib, nib

In a UIViewController am detecting the view's change in orientation using didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation.  I then load a nib that corresponds to the correct device orientation using [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed: owner: options:].  Works ok, but is a little clunky looking.  Is there a way of animating the change?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your change with a beginAnimations, like this:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown
                         forView:window cache:YES]; // You can change the effect
    /*
     * YOUR CODE HERE
     */
[UIView commitAnimations];
```